# Rails 3.0 Routing Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've created a named route like follows:

```
match 'deactivate/:id' => 'events#deactivateEvent', :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}, :via => [:get, :post]
```

In my view I have this line of code:

```
 <%= link_to 'Deactivate', deactivate_path(@event.id) %>
```

Now I get the following error:
NoMethodError in Events#show

Showing C:/Users/redbush/Desktop/ticket/app/views/events/show.html.erb where line #33 raised:

undefined method `deactivate_path' for #<#:0x817f050>

Extracted source (around line #33):

```
 30: <% end %>
 31: 
 32: <% if @event.approval && !@event.deactivated && @event.active && @event.sales_start < Time.now %>
 33:    <%= link_to 'Deactivate', deactivate_path(@event.id) %>
 34: <% end %>
```

So I am really confused on why this is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're setting up a manual `match` path, you need to provide it with the named route you want to use, using the `:as` parameter:

```
match 'deactivate/:id' => 'events#deactivateEvent', 
      :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}, 
      :via => [:get, :post], 
      :as => :deactivate
```

(See 3.6 Naming Routes in the [Rails Routing guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html))

Comment: better without the period at the end :) +1 for (same) answer though

Comment: Great that worked. What do you mean by manual? I am confused because, for example, this works fine match 'home' => 'pages#index', :via => :get

Comment: Well when you use something like `resource :posts` it automatically creates `posts_path`, `edit_post_path`, etc. But when you just use a `match` statement, Rails won't automatically know what `xxxxx_path` name you want to use.

Comment: So when using match I should always use :as?

Comment: If you want to be able to do something like `<%= link_to deactivate_path(@event.id) ...` instead of `<%= link_to "/deactivate/#{@event.id}" ...`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
:as => :deactivate
```

at the end of your route